# How to draw a corresponding tree diagram based on the arrangement and combination problem?

Tags: plotting

**A certain school offers 4 elective courses in physical education (A, B, C, D) and 4 elective courses in art (a, b, c, d). Students need to take 2 or 3 courses from these 8 courses, and at least 1 elective course is required for each type of elective course. How many different course selection options are there?**

Category Discussion:

1.When 2 courses are selected, only one gate can be selected for each gate. There are 4 * 4=16 types

2.When 3 courses are selected, 2 courses will be selected for sports and 1 course will be selected for art; Or choose 1 sports course and 2 art courses. There are 4 * 6+6 * 4=48 options

So, there are a total of 16+48=64 selection methods

How to draw the corresponding tree diagram based on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly is desired. Here is a way to illustrate combinations:

```
s = CharacterRange["A", "D"];
a = CharacterRange["a", "d"];
two = Join @@ Outer[UndirectedEdge, s, a];
three1 = Join @@ Outer[UndirectedEdge, s, Subsets[a, {2}], 1];
three2 = Join @@ Outer[UndirectedEdge, a, Subsets[s, {2}], 1];
gtwo = Graph[two, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"];
gthree1 = 
  Graph[three1, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"];
gthree2 = 
  Graph[three2, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"];
g = Graph[Join[two, three1, three2], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"];
```

Visualizing:

```
res = Column[{Row[{"Number of 2 course options:", 
     Length[EdgeList[gtwo]]}], gtwo,
   Row[{"Number of 3 course options with 1 sport elective:", 
     Length[EdgeList[gthree1]]}], gthree1,
   Row[{"Number of 3 course options with 1 art elective:", 
     Length[EdgeList[gthree2]]}], gthree2,
   Row[{"Number of  2 or3 course options with at least 1 from each
type:", Length[EdgeList[g]]}], g
   }, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This effect is very shocking!

Comment: Thank you. What we need is this effect！